# printf with a width modifier fails to print the value

Tags: c++, printf, column-width

In a C++ program, under Windows 7 using VS2013 and under Ubuntu 14.04.1 using g++ 4.6, I am mystified by the operation of printf().

With the 2nd width modifier, this prints a space instead of a 0.
When set to another value, e.g., -1, it prints it. Without the modifier, it prints a 0, as expected.

I pasted the actual, relevant code into another program and it behaved the same way.

What could be the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x = 1, z = 0;
    printf ("%2.d: %2.d\n", x, z); // fails to print 0
    printf ("%2.d: %d\n", x, z);  // 2nd %2. absent, prints as expected
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 1:   
 1: 0
```

Comment: You need another number after the '.', or an asterisk '*'. For instance, %2.2d would print a minimum of 2 digits. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point should go to the left

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1, z = 0;
    printf ("%.2d: %.2d\n", x, z); // fails to print 0
    printf ("%.2d: %d\n", x, z);  // 2nd %2. absent, prints as expected
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
01: 00
01: 0
```

Comment: I actually think he wants `%2.1d`

Comment: Yes, I want a width of 2 columns. The addition of the precision specifier (%2.1d) did the trick, _thanks a lot_.      Nowhere did I read that you have to have a precision specifier for the width specifier to work, in fact, they're explicitly described as being independent of one another.  Weirdest thing - I thought I knew printf().